# Can I get a notification (mail) when a comment or answer has been arrived?

Tags: notifications, comments

after a while searching for this question I did'nt find any answer.

I think I can react much faster if I get a notification when a comment or answer has been arrived.

How can I configure this in StackExchange?

Comment: Have you searched the [Meta Stack Site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?  Here is a discussion on this [topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Interesting, that this topic has no much pros and cons. When I have more time, i'll read this topic in depth.